# C# Thread not changing the text box values the second time

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating an application that involves using threads. Everything works until I click the button for the second time. Nothing happens on the second time the button is clicked. Its like the first time all the stuff loads and then just locks the values of the text boxes. The stuff in red is just private links that cannot be shown. Its not the links because they work just fine the first time. They just won't work the second time. I hope what I just said wasn't too confusing.

[image: Image of my code]

Comment: I am expecting the data being pulled from the strings to change. It works perfectly if I don't put the webrequest and everything into a thread. If I don't make a thread for the webrequest it will then freeze my application until is is done fetching the data, and I do not want this to happen.

Comment: You have a number of issues with your code - most of which Kirill has done an excellent job of pointing out - but one other one is that `WebClient` implements `IDisposable` so you must call `.Dispose()` on it when you are done with it. You are doing `new WebClient().DownloadString(...)` so you don't have the opportunity to dispose it. Kirill's answer correctly uses the `using` keyword to ensure this happens.

Comment: Yes what he gave me would be correct, but it is way to slow.

Comment: @VizenDev - You could parallelize the calls, but the slowest of the three would always be your bottleneck. Do you know the time it takes for each of the three?

Comment: For my code or Kirills?

Comment: @VizenDev - It doesn't matter - the time it takes to purely run each `DownloadString`.

Comment: @VizenDev - It would have been very nice if you didn't upload an image for your code. Text is much better.

Answer (score 1):

`name1`, `name2`, `name3` are all downloaded *when the form is created*, they're just bound to the textboxes when you press the button the first time.

`_name1()`, `_name2()`, `_name3()` methods are just object instantiations and have no side effects of any kind (put differently, they don't do anything).

And all the threading stuff is just fluff - you're calling methods that don't do anything and then aborting the threads (thereby aborting something that isn't doing anything anyway). This has zero effect on the execution in any way as the code is currently written, even when executed the first time.

The simple, synchronous fix for your code will look like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        textBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("<your URL here>");
        textBox2.Text = client.DownloadString("<your URL here>");
        textBox3.Text = client.DownloadString("<your URL here>");
    }
}
```

Seeing as you're using threads, your goal is obviously non-blocking, asynchronous execution. The easiest way to achieve it while preserving the sequencing of operations is with `async/await`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Disabling the button ensures that it's not pressed
    // again while the first request is still in flight.
    materialRaisedButton1.Enabled = false;

    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            // Execute async downloads in parallel:
            Task<string>[] parallelDownloads = new[] {
                client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("<your URL here>"),
                client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("<your URL here>"),
                client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("<your URL here>")
            };

            // Collect results.
            string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(parallelDownloads);

            // Update all textboxes at the same time.
            textBox1.Text = results[0];
            textBox2.Text = results[1];
            textBox3.Text = results[2];
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        materialRaisedButton1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, the only thing is, for each of the text boxes it has a delay in between collecting the data

Comment: @VizenDev - That's because it takes time to collect the data.

Comment: How would I be able to not have a delay on the data being collected like I do on my code. There is no wait time and as soon as the buttons are clicked they update the text boxes values.

Comment: @VizenDev - You can't have no delay if you expect the button click to start the process. Unless you have a flux capacitor. ;-)

Comment: Okay so the latest code you just updated works, but its just to slow. I need my application to be fast and something to happen when the button is clicked. Not like 3 seconds after it is clicked.

Comment: @VizenDev, the beauty of `Task`s + `async/await` is how simple they make controlling async operation flow. If you need something running in parallel, you fire off a bunch of tasks and then `await` them at the rendezvous point. I've tweaked the answer to execute web service requests in parallel. If things are still "slow" after this, your bottleneck is in the web service calls themselves (server response + network latency), which is outside the scope of your question.